# BULK INSERT - error with binary datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, sql-server-2014, bulkinsert

I'm using `sqlcmd` to write data to a ***text*** file. This data contains column with ***binary datatype***. This is the command:

`sqlcmd -E -Q "' + @queryCommand + '" -o "' + @filePath + '" -s "," -W`

Now, I'm using `BULK INSERT` to import that data into my database. This is the command (just the importand part):

```
N'BULK INSERT ' + @tableName + ' FROM ''' + @importFilePath + ''' WITH 
      (
          ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000,
          TABLOCK,
          FIRSTROW = 3,
          FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
          ROWTERMINATOR = ''\r\n'',
          DATAFILETYPE = ''widenative'',
          codepage = ''1251''
      )'
```

For the `DATAFILETYPE` I tried both ***native*** and ***widenative***, and for the `ROWTERMINATOR` I tried ***0x0a***, ***\r\n*** and ***\n***. I think `CODEPAGE` is irrelevant here (I found it in some other answer) because I tried without it also.

The error I'm getting here is:

> *The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 2. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.*

When I'm using normal `BULK INSERT`:

```
N'BULK INSERT ' + @tableName + ' FROM ''' + @importFilePath + ''' WITH 
      (
          ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000,
          TABLOCK,
          FIRSTROW = 3,
          FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
          ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
      )'
```

I get the following error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 10 (***Column with binary datatype***).

Btw, this is how the ***text*** file looks like:

```
SomeId,...,SomethingBinary,...
--,------,-----------,-------------,------
11FF47D0-B4A8-452A-9E3F-41BF201C2669,...,0x010005000A741F2B40208AA43B02000000000000,...
```

Comment: please create a minimal sqlfiddle with schema and at last one failing row

Comment: How am I suppose to create text file there? I need text file from which to import...

Comment: good point. still if I had schema, exact code, and even a single text line that I could save to a local file....

Comment: here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e529

Comment: i'm using sql server 2014

Comment: you sure about that command, I can't find it in the docs

Comment: maan. look at this 'hack' - in the select I wrote binary as a string without '0x' and it worked (e.g. '010005000A741F2B40208AA43B02000000000000')

Comment: again, it even worked without FORMATFILE ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it took a while but I found several  problems:

First, your table definition (in the SQLFiddle) was:

```
create table [Test]
(
    [Id] uniqueidentifier not null,
    [SomeValue] int not null,
    [BinaryCol] binary not null   -- this is binary(1) !!
);
```

and should be

```
create table [Test]
(
    [Id] uniqueidentifier not null,
    [SomeValue] int not null,
    [BinaryCol] varbinary(max) not null  -- or the appropriate size
);
```

Always specify a size for datatypes!

Secondly, I used a format file generated from the correct table definition:

```
 bcp tmp.dbo.Test format nul -c -x -f C:\temp\Import.xml -t, -T

Output:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="37"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="12"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Id" xsi:type="SQLUNIQUEID"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="SomeValue" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="BinaryCol" xsi:type="SQLVARYBIN"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I had to strip out the `'0x'` of all the column 3 data:

```
Id,SomeValue,BinaryCol
--,---------,---------
3D30DF1B-D67B-4A2D-B79C-EBDC013928C3,1,010005000A741F2B40208AA43B02000000000000
B896ECB2-39A2-4888-9293-DE382BDBA0B7,2,010005000A741F2B40208AA43B02000000000000
7B053980-DD74-48E3-A348-0567A421E958,3,010005000A741F2B40208AA43B02000000000000
```

Then I imported with:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Test FROM 'C:\temp\res.txt' WITH 
(
    ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000,
    TABLOCK,
    FIRSTROW = 3,
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\temp\Import.xml'
)
```

Comment: yea I see, but I have millions of rows - I can't edit them like this (remove 0x) ^

Comment: why not? search and replace?

Comment: I don't wanna lose 20+ minutes on search and replace, but as I can see that's the only option for now

Comment: I dont' even need FORMATFILE, I could just remove '0x' and it works